# focusNode returns undefined when selecting the whole element

Tags: javascript, jquery, getselection

I need to identify the id's of the begin and end <p> elements of a text selection. I have written the following:

```
  $(document).on('keydown', function ( e ) {
        if ((e.metaKey ) && (String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase() === 'c') ) {
          var selectedText = document.getSelection();
          if (selectedText && selectedText != '') {
            var selectedBeginId = $(selectedText.anchorNode.parentNode).attr('id');
            var selectedEndId = $(selectedText.focusNode.parentNode).attr('id');
            alert(selectedBeginId + ' - ' + selectedEndId);
          } else {
            alert('No passage selected');
          }
        }
    });
```

The HTML is something like this:

```
 <body>
      <p id="p-001">1 Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p id="p-002">2 Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p id="p-003">3 Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p id="p-004">4 Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p id="p-005">5 Lorem ipsum</p>
      <p id="p-006">6 Lorem ipsum</p>
  </body>
```

When I select some text range and press meta+c it displays the beginning and end <p> id's. However, if the selection ends at the end of a paragraph, sometimes it returns selectedEndId as *undefined*.
Can anyone explain why and how to solve it?
I have observed this error in Safari, Chrome and Opera, but not in FF.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to recreate the problem, it happens when you select a line then the one just below by stopping before the first character (difficult to explain).

The problem is that the browser thinks that you select the body, I can not explain it but I found a solution, here is a code that works for me :

```
 var selectedEndId;
 if($(selectedText.focusNode.parentNode)[0] != document.body){
   selectedEndId = $(selectedText.focusNode.parentNode).attr('id');
 }else{
   selectedEndId = selectedBeginId;
 }
```

I added it just below the line :

```
      var selectedBeginId = $(selectedText.anchorNode.parentNode).attr('id');
```

As you can see, my code works but it could pose other problems.
I hope I put you on the track !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks abvlle, I followed on your suggestion and I found the solution. As you indicated, the selection somehow falls through the two elements, where the parentnode will point not at the <p> element, but at its parent (the body or something else), and the focusNode will point at the next element. Therefore, I wrote this:

```
$(document).on('keydown', function ( e ) {
    if ((e.metaKey ) && (String.fromCharCode(e.which).toLowerCase() === 'c') ) {
      var selectedText = document.getSelection();
      if (selectedText && selectedText != '') {
        var selectedBeginId = $(selectedText.anchorNode.parentNode).attr('id');
        var selectedEndId = $(selectedText.focusNode.parentNode).attr('id');
        var selectedEnd = $(selectedText.focusNode.parentNode);
        if (!$(selectedEnd).is('p')) {
          selectedEndId = ($(selectedText.focusNode).prev().attr('id'));
        }
        alert(selectedBeginId + ' - ' + selectedEndId);
      } else {
        alert('No passage selected');
      }
    }
});
```

This works nicely. Thanks for your help!